# Option forward in Google Chat

Tags: google-chat

Is there a way that I can achieve forward option in Google chat, to forward a message from one group to another group. I see neither inbuilt support nor an extension for it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google chat doesn't have a way to forward messages to another space. You may forward it to your inbox, though.